# Osm2pgsql, permission denied when creating node cache file

Tags: osm2pgsql, postgresql-10

This is probably a dumb issue but I'm kind of stuck while trying to import a big data set into an existing database with [`osm2pgsql`](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql).

More specifically, I'm getting a `permission denied` error when using the `--flat-nodes` flag followed by `/mnt/nodes/flatnodes.bin`, whereas typing just `flatnodes.bin` does not throw this error. I'm using four disks, one is for the system disk, which I don't want to use neither for the database, the `flatnodes.bin` nor the downloaded data set due to limited size (50GB); the bigger disk is used to store the PostgreSQL database and it is here that I intend to import the map into; a third one, which is used to store the `flatnodes.bin` files used during the import process; and finally a fourth disk, which is where the downloaded data (planet-latest.osm.pbf) is stored. These last two are deleted at the end of the import process. Here's what I'm typing into the command line:

`postgres@map-server / $ osm2pgsql -c -d postgres --slim -C 30000 --flat-nodes /mnt/nodes/flatnodes.bin /mnt/data/planet-latest.osm.pbf`

Here's what I'm getting in return:

```
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.88.1 (64bit id space)

Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=30000MB, maxblocks=3840000*8192, allocation method=11
Mid: loading persistent node cache from flatnodes.bin
Failed to create node cache file: Permission denied
Error occurred, cleaning up
```

If I do it as root, I get this in return:

```
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Error: Connection to database failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Doing all this on Ubuntu Bionic with PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.5.0 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, a dumb issue. The issue was file permissions, with `/mnt/nodes/flatenodes.bin` being owned by the root user, with exclusive write permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 29 12:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Oct 29 12:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0 Oct 29 13:39 flatnodes.bin
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Oct 29 12:09 lost+found
```

Granting write-read-execute permissions to everyone did the trick (`chmod 777 /mnt/nodes/flatnodes.bin`). Since the file will be deleted after the import process (I will not do regular updates of the database), such a generous privilege policy should not be an issue. This is what I got after granting said permissions, with the import process starting without issues:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 29 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Oct 29 12:10 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Oct 29 13:39 flatnodes.bin
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Oct 29 12:09 lost+found
```

And the log after typing `osm2pgsql -c -d postgres --slim --drop -C 30000 --flat-nodes /mnt/nodes/flatnodes.bin /mnt/data/planet-latest.osm.pbf` (since the database will not be updated regularly, we can instruct osm2pgs2l not to index the slim tables by adding the `--drop` flag, thus saving time and disk space):

```
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 3857 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=30000MB, maxblocks=480000*65536, allocation method=11
Mid: loading persistent node cache from /mnt/nodes/flatnodes.bin
Mid: pgsql, cache=30000
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

Reading in file: /mnt/data/planet-latest.osm.pbf
Using PBF parser.
```